# Can't create custom field

Tags: custom-fields, contributions

I can't seem to create any custom fields.  I'm on the `/civicrm/admin/custom/group` page and I choose the "Add Set of Custom Fields" button.  After filling out the form (setting "Used For" = Contribution) and hitting the Save button, I'm taken back to the `/civicrm/admin/custom/group` page, but my new Custom Data group isn't visible.

There are no error messages in the browser, nor in Watchdog.  What could be going wrong here?  I'm logged in as user_id=1.

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.10 on Drupal 7.41.

Comment: Does the new Set of Fields show in the database in table civicrm_custom_group, ie is it being created but your page isn't loading it?

Comment: Do you know how/have you tried creating the custom group from the API explorer or the Drush commandline? Might give you a chance to see an error message.

Comment: Have you moved the database recently? Check your database triggers.

Answer (score -1):

Is there an error in the log file in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/ ?

Comment: Nope, no new entries there.